# Make multiple get requests and track their responses in Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have to make get requests to a slow API and keep track of the response status.  I can only fetch the data (with another get request and a different url) once the initial dispatch status is 'Done'.  Some search queries are fetched faster than others, so I have to keep that in mind as well

I used the javascript setTimeout function and waited 20 seconds for all the search queries to finish.  This is a hit or miss approach as some queries are fetched faster than 20 seconds and some later

```
async function get_dispatch_state(sid) {
  let dispatchState = "";
  let json = await axios.get(
    `https://digitals.devfg.test.com:8089/services/search/jobs/${sid}?output_mode=json`,
    {
      method: "get",
      auth: auth,
      headers: options
    }
  );
  dispatchState = json.data.entry[0]["content"].dispatchState;
  return dispatchState;
}

function get__data() {
  axios({
    method: "get",
    url: `https://digitalsp.devfg.test.com:8089/services/search/jobs/test_search_1/results?output_mode=json`,
    auth: auth,
    headers: options
  })
    .then(datax => {
      fraud_line_1d = datax.data;
      console.log("***Fraud line 1****" + JSON.stringify(fraud_line_1d));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("second error is " + error);
    });
// repeat other get requests
}


 setTimeout(function() {
       get_data();
}, 20000);
```

All data is eventually fetched but at different intervals depending on how large the search query is.  I need some advice on the best way to fetch the data once the dispatch status is Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Promise.all()** method returns a single *Promise* that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
function get_dispatch_state(sid) {
    return axios.get(
        `https://digitals.devfg.test.com:8089/services/search/jobs/${sid}?output_mode=json`,
        {
            method: 'get',
            auth: auth,
            headers: options
        }
    )
        .then(json => {
            return json.data.entry[0]['content'].dispatchState;
        });
}

function get__data() {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://digitalsp.devfg.test.com:8089/services/search/jobs/test_search_1/results?output_mode=json`,
        auth: auth,
        headers: options
    })
        .then(datax => {
            fraud_line_1d = datax.data;
            return JSON.stringify(fraud_line_1d);
        });
    // repeat other get requests
}


Promise.all([get_dispatch_state() , get__data()])
.then(data => {
    // Array with the response of both request at the same time    
})
```

> Small sample of how we should implement it.

More information on the subject [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: very interesting, I need to learn more about promises and async coding in javascript.  thnx

Comment: @sharsart If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.